# javascript:void(0) or onclick="return false" for <a> - which is better?

Tags: javascript

There is a javascript-based interface - so I need not to support work without javascript.

I have an

```
<a>Something</a>
```

elements with JS code, which binds on click event - so, I don't want page reload after user's click.

Which way is better?

```
1. <a href="javascript:void(0)">Something</a>
2. <a href="#" onclick="return false;">Something</a>
```

What advantages and disadvantages of each method?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451560/ideal-value-for-a-href-when-used-for-a-js-event

Comment: duplicate ? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245868/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-methods-of-putting-javascript-in-an

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are poor choices. Presentation shouldn't mix with content. That means no `javascript:` URIs, and definitely no `onclick` attributes.

The way to do it:

```
<a id="myLink">Something</a>
<script>
    function myFunction(...) { ... }
    document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
</script>
```

Comment: In general, it is a second way - event listener. I have written onclick="..." for simplicity. I use JQuery - so 
$("#elementId").bind("click", function(){return false;});
Thank you.

Comment: You're right that both are poor choices, but this is even worse: it doesn't work in IE. And how does this putting a `<script>` element in immediately after the `<a>` actually improve things from a separation-of-concerns perspective?

Comment: Sigh. I'm not getting deeply into the IE-is-bad-so-I'm-not-going-to-support-it issue again. I'll limit myself to pointing out that it's the user's choice which browser they use, not yours, and most users neither know nor care which browser they use. Some simply cannot switch. This case isn't even controversial: `addEventListener` doesn't even work in the current version of IE (8), meaning your code doesn't work in something like 50% of people's browsers. Do you really want to exclude 50% of people from using your website?

Comment: OK, that's your choice. However, it's fair to assume that the person asking the original question will be concerned about IE.

Comment: Another downside: this will cause the link not to be styled like other links, e.g. by default it wouldn't be underlined, because the `href` attribute is missing.

Comment: Are AJAX interactions not a valid case for an anchor that doesn't go anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Neither. If your link doesn't go anywhere, don't use an `<a>` element. Use a `<span>` or something else appropriate and add CSS to style it as you wish.

Comment: Actually, an `<a>` element is better as it's more semantically correct. Unless everything is clickable, like a full-blown web app, an `<a>` element will be more likely to be expected as clickable than a `<span>`.

Comment: Why is it more semantically correct if it's not acting as a link or an anchor?

Comment: Because a `<span>` isn't semantically *anything*. An `<a>` is a little closer as you click on it, even though it isn't quite a link. However, like I said earlier, if I'm writing a full-blown standalone webapp, chances are these semantic differences are less important and I'll just stick with one or the other; probably `<span>`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that `<span>` conveys no semantic meaning. However, since the question is asking about an `<a>` element with `onclick="return false;"`, I assumed the OP wanted the link to do precisely nothing, making it entirely pointless as a link. Re-reading the question, I think I misunderstood.