# How can I write a non-clickable link that runs a javascript function upon click?

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question was answered before, here: [javascript:void(0) or onclick="return false" for <a> - which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465750/javascriptvoid0-or-onclick-return-false-for-a-which-is-better)

However, the solution did not work for me.

Here's the applicable code:

HTML:

```
<a id="Skip">Skip</a>
```

Javascript:

```
   var Skip = document.getElementById("Skip");
   Skip.addEventListener('click', reloadPage(), true);

   function reloadPage() {
        window.location.href = "play.php";
    }
```

When I click on "Skip," nothing happens. I would like to keep the `window.location.href` method of reloading as I'd like to add $_GET variables to it.

Comment: `href="#"` and use `return false` to stop the # being added to the url in your browser.

Comment: In Javascript, you need be careful about function() or function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Skip.addEventListener('click', reloadPage(), true);
//                                       ^^-------------------
```

Should be:

```
Skip.addEventListener('click', reloadPage, true);
```

You want the callback to be `reloadPage` not what `reloadPage` returns.

Comment: This still doesn't do anything. Here's a jsFiddle with test code. http://jsfiddle.net/m2B2M/1/

Comment: That JSFiddle was not working because you had a syntax error - getElementByID instead of getElementById. Check this out - it's working. It will not redirect to http://www.google.com because that violates the same origin policy, but I threw in an alert to show you the code was being called. http://jsfiddle.net/m2B2M/3/ On clicking it will alert, and if you watched a console you would get an error like "Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." (on Chrome), but it should work for you.

Comment: Alright. This answer with a couple fixes (I didn't know that each <script></script> was treated differently) fixed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have pass function pointer to addEventListener. So that when click happen it calls that method. You don't want to call the method coz that return nothing

For eg :

```
Skip. addEventListener('click', reloadPage, true);
```

you can also do like what you have written but only if your method return another function

for eg

```
Skip. addEventListener('click', reloadPage(), true);
function reloadPage() {
     return function(){
        // do something interesting.
     }
}
```